# React architecture - Is it considered good practice to extract pure functions from React components to a separate file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, architecture

So, the question is basically in the headline already. And I am not talking just about React, I am talking about Vue.js also. In my components I have lot of pure functions, which are framework agnostic (if they are imported into framework, they work in React or Vue or Angular out of the box). The other thing is that this pure functions can be reused in other components.

Now, I know that I CAN export function and use them in components, this is not the question. The question is - Is it considered good practice to extract those pure functions to a separate file (and folder), and import them in React components??

Comment: Indeed, not just React, not even just JS, separate files are considered good practice were possible.  Single files with 1000's of lines of code is not ideal.